# Multiple carousel doesn't want to synchronize

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have weird problem with my carousel. I'm using carouFredSel to make an unusual slider for my page. It almost works but with one problem. After a page has loaded, the carousel shows the first image and the first title. But when the carousel scrolls to the next picture, it misses the second picture and shows the third one but with the second picture's title. This problem also appeared with my hover effect. When I hover the thumb it shows good title but wrong picture.

I don't know how to explain this better. If I make myself unclear, please let me know and I will try to describe the problem differently.

How can I synchronize pictures with titles?

Working fiddle: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78y8n4f8/2/)

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="news-mp-container">
    <div class="news-mp-slider" id="newsMPSlider">
        <div class="images-wrapper">
            <div class="news-mp-slider-bigone">
                <div id="sliderBigPhotoWrapper">
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticlePhoto_101">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1426085277646_480x360.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticlePhoto_99">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1426085055263_480x360.png"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticlePhoto_98">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/142479021075_480x360.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticlePhoto_97">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1424790022510_480x360.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticlePhoto_96">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1424789916934_480x360.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticlePhoto_95">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1424789591806_480x360.png"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="news-mp-slider-thumbs">
                <div id="sliderThumbsWrapper">
                    <a href="news,single?id=101" id="sliderArticleThumb_101">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1426085277646_62x62.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticleThumb_99">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1426085055263_62x62.png"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticleThumb_98">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/142479021075_62x62.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticleThumb_97">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1424790022510_62x62.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticleThumb_96">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1424789916934_62x62.jpg"/>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" id="sliderArticleThumb_95">
                        <img src="http://magsite.pl/jsfiddleimg/articles/1424789591806_62x62.png"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="news-mp-slider-title-holder">
            <div id="sliderTextWrapper">
                <div id="sliderArticleTitle_101" class="news-mp-slider-text">
                    <a href="#" class="news-mp-title">
                        <h4>Bacon ipsum</h4>
                    </a>
                    <p class="news-mp-shortdesc">Bacon ipsum dolor amet kevin short ribs ham, tenderloin picanha biltong rump ribeye tail leberkas.</p>
                </div>
                <div id="sliderArticleTitle_99" class="news-mp-slider-text">
                    <a href="#" class="news-mp-title">
                        <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
                    </a>
                    <p class="news-mp-shortdesc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lacus velit,...</p>
                </div>
                <div id="sliderArticleTitle_98" class="news-mp-slider-text">
                    <a href="#" class="news-mp-title">
                        <h4>Veggie ipsum</h4>
                    </a>
                    <p class="news-mp-shortdesc">Veggies es bonus vobis, proinde vos postulo essum magis kohlrabi welsh onion...</p>
                </div>
                <div id="sliderArticleTitle_97" class="news-mp-slider-text">
                    <a href="#" class="news-mp-title">
                        <h4>Tuna ipsum</h4>
                    </a>
                    <p class="news-mp-shortdesc">Snook peamouth crocodile shark collared dogfish weever trout cod slender mola Modoc </p>
                </div>
                <div id="sliderArticleTitle_96" class="news-mp-slider-text">
                    <a href="#" class="news-mp-title">
                        <h4>Yippiyo ipsum</h4>
                    </a>
                    <p class="news-mp-shortdesc">Yippiyo ipsizzle i'm in the shizzle sizzle amizzle, consectetuer adipiscing...</p>
                </div>
                <div id="sliderArticleTitle_95" class="news-mp-slider-text">
                    <a href="#" class="news-mp-title">
                        <h4>Beer ipsum</h4>
                    </a>
                    <p class="news-mp-shortdesc">degrees plato krausen, mash ipa bacterial pint glass. krug cask conditioned...</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#sliderBigPhotoWrapper').carouFredSel({
    responsive: false,
    circular: false,
    auto: {
        fx: 'crossfade',
        duration: 500,
        timeoutDuration: 6000,
        pauseOnHover: true
    },
    scroll: {
        fx: 'crossfade',
        duration: 500,
        pauseOnHover: true
    },
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        width: '460px',
        height: '360px'
    }
});

$('#sliderTextWrapper').carouFredSel({
    responsive: false,
    circular: false,
    synchronise: ['#sliderBigPhotoWrapper', true, true],
    auto: {
        fx: 'crossfade',
        duration: 500,
        timeoutDuration: 6000,
    },
    scroll: {
        fx: 'crossfade',
        duration: 500,
    },
    items: {
        visible: 1,
        width: '460px',
        height: 'auto'
    }
});
$('#sliderThumbsWrapper').on('mouseenter', 'a', function () {
    console.log('hover start');
    n = $(this).attr('id').split('_').pop();
    console.log('n: ' + n);
    console.log('before first trigger - #sliderArticlePhoto_' + n);
    $('#sliderBigPhotoWrapper').trigger('slideTo', '#sliderArticlePhoto_' + n);
    console.log('after first trigger');
    console.log('before second trigger - #sliderArticleTitle_' + n);
    $('#sliderTextWrapper').trigger('slideTo', '#sliderArticleTitle_' + n);
    console.log('after second trigger');
    $('#sliderBigPhotoWrapper').trigger('stop');
    console.log('hover end');
    return false;
});
```

and CSS:

```
.news-mp-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 480px;
}
.news-mp-container * {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}
.news-mp-container img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
/*SLIDER*/
 .news-mp-slider {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
}
.news-mp-slider img {
    width: 100%;
}
.news-mp-slider .news-mp-title {
    display: inline-block;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-size: 2.2rem;
    margin: 0;
}
.news-mp-slider .news-mp-title h4{
    margin: 0.5em 0;
}
.news-mp-slider .news-mp-shortdesc {
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
.news-mp-slider-bigone {
    height: 360px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.news-mp-slider-bigone a, .news-mp-slider-bigone img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 480px;
}
.news-mp-slider-bigone img {
    width: 100%;
}
.news-mp-slider-thumbs {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 20;
}
.news-mp-slider-thumbs a {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 14px;
    width: 65px;
    /*        width: calc(100% / 6 - 10px);*/
    height: 65px;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 3px solid #0282cd;
}
.news-mp-slider-thumbs a:hover {
    border-color: #f7be0d;
}
.news-mp-slider-thumbs a:last-child {
    margin: 0;
}
.news-mp-slider-thumbs img {
    display: block;
    /*float: left;*/
    width: 62px;
    height: 62px;
}
.news-mp-slider-title-holder {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    padding: 10px 0 5px;
}
.news-mp-slider-text {
    width: 460px;
}
```

I hope you guys can help because I can't find any solution.